# How to use a dynamic variable in Laravel group routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

for example:

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang?}'], function () {
 //..
 });
```

create a variable in middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){

$lang = session('locale');

App::setLocale($lang);

return $next($request);      
});
```

also tried to get the data in the prefix, but got null

```
Route::group(['prefix' =>  config('app.locale')], function () {
//..
});
```

or

```
Route::group(['prefix' =>  session('locale')], function () {
//..
});
```

change language separate route through session

```
Route::get('setlocale/{locale}', function ($locale) {

session(['locale' => $locale]);

return redirect()->back();

})->name('setlocale');
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to group your routes under a `lang` route, you can create your own middleware and group your routes under that middleware, and use this code inside of it:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
     $lang = request->get('locale');
     $currentLang = App::getLocale();

     //If locale exists in the url and it's changed
     if($lang && $lang != $currentLang) App::setLocale($lang);

     //If locale doesn't exist in the url, fallback to default locale
     if(!$lang) App::setLocale('en');

     return $next($request);      
 });
```

The url should be `data/store?locale=en`, ur url should always append `locale` after `?` in the url, otherwise, your default `locale` will be used

**EDIT:** Since your routes include `locale` as a part of the url, and not as a request param, then I suggest you use a library to handle this for you, because you will have a lot of stuff to do before you will be able to have a working example: [`Laravel localization mcmara`](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization)

Comment: in my url not added `domain.com/fr/` although `Ap::getLocale ()` - fr

Comment: I dont understand you?

Comment: I need to add to url for all routes after domain locale like this `domain.com/locale/` only if this is not the default locale